# Android API 24. No resource identifier found for attribute 'minimalSize' in package 'android'

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-7.0-nougat

I have an issue with `android:minimalSize` inside `activity - layout` in my manifest file. It says

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'minimalSize' in package
>   'android'

It is weird. Since from here https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html#configuring it seems that `android:minimalSize` is a legit attribute for multi-window mode.

Moreover, other attributes inside `activity - layout` like `android:defaultHeight` and `android:defaultWidth` are OK.

Maybe someone had a similar issue.

App level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        //...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        //...
    }
    //...
}

dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
//...
<activity
    //...
    android:resizeableActivity="true">
    <layout android:minimalSize="450dp" />
    //...
</activity>
//...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the [New APIs in Developer Preview 4](https://developer.android.com/preview/support.html#new):

> The Multi-Window `android:minimalHeight` and `android:minimalWidth` attributes have been renamed to `android:minHeight` and `android:minWidth`.

The [documentation page you linked to](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html#configuring) was also updated to refer to the new names.

Comment: `minimalSize` was replaced with `minimalHeight` and `minimalWidth` in [Developer Preview 2](https://developer.android.com/preview/support.html#dp2-new).

I don't see `minimialSize`, `minimalHeight`, or `minimalWidth` on the English documentation page - are you in a specific language that might not be updated yet?